# Rewrite module replace char # to URL equivalent %23

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, fragment-identifier

How to replace in URL char # to its URL equivalent %23? Example:

`https://example.com/common/rest/sitck?Param1=46694#2205923&Code=123`

to

`https://example.com/common/rest/sitck?Param1=46694%232205923&Code=123`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to replace a `#` in a URL using a rewrite rule.  The hash and everything that comes after it is called the "fragment identifier."  That part of the URL is **never sent to the server**.  It is client side only.  Therefore it is not possible to manipulate it in a rewrite rule on the server.

The best you can do is examine the URL with client-side JavaScript.  You can get and set the URL using the `location.href` variable in your web page.